# OpenFire Difference between group and chat group

Tags: openfire

I am trying to build a company wise chat application in openfire. Here company will be treated as group and its employees will be treated as user.
Could anyone please tell me where to create group in admin panel i.e in user/group option or chatroom group option and what is the difference between group in user/group and group in group chat option in layman language

Answer (score 1):

A "group" in context of users is a defined set of users. A "Group Chat" is a multi-user chat room.

The two have little to do with eachother (only that Openfire will allow you to use groups when configuring room permissions).